# What is the datatype for ratings in mysql?

Tags: android, mysql

I am creating an android application in which users can rate trips similarly in [playstore](https://play.google.com/store). So ,I used datatype `DECIMAL(3,2)` for storing ratings.

But, the problem is that it will allow average rating values more than 5 like up to `9.99`...I want to show average ratings from `0.0 to 5.0`. Then what should be my data type?

Should I use `enum{1,2,3,4,5}`?

Comment: you can simply store rating as string and after retrieving it in your app,you can convert it to double.

Comment: @W-I-Z-A-R-D ya, using rating bar. but, when other people see it, I have to retrieve the average ratings. So, i have to store ratings from rating bar.

Comment: If all your ratings are between 0 and 5, why are you concerned about the average not being within the same interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use `tinyint` for storing ratings n the database. Then, we can retrieve average using MySQL aggregate functions like [AVG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm).

Comment: That is incorrect.  Read the comments on that answer.  The ENUM type is a string object.  You would not be able to do mathematical calculations on it like AVG.  You would need to use a numeric data type like TINYINT if you would like to do numeric functions.

Comment: Restrict the answers in the application.

Comment: Actually, I tried a sqlfiddle and AVG actually does seem to work.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb23ef/1

Answer (score 1):

you can put validation on inserting rating.. that if rating is above 5.0 than display dialogbox. or toast notification that rating must be in range between 0.0 to 5.0

Answer (score 0):

`RatingBar` method `public float getRating ()` will return float value you can store as string and you can convert into float while getting rat and `RatingBar` have also method `public void setStepSize (float stepSize)` where stepSize is the step size of this rating bar. For example, if half-star granularity is wanted, this would be 0.5.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />
```